# read table from file , each row different number of columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a data file where each row has a different number of columns, like this:

```
x   x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x   x   x   x
x   x
x   x   x   x   x
x   x   x
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x
x   x   x   x   x
```

How can I read this into LaTeX and loop through the rows and columns appropriately?  I will use the data (coordinates) to draw various numbers of rectangles with **TikZ**

I can't get it to work with `\pgfplotstableread`

(Note, I can get `\pgfplotstableread` to work with square matrices, but not "jagged matrices" as described above).

Answer (score 6):

You could read it with latex, but simpler is just to edit it to normal tex syntax. If I save your example as `d.txt` then a commandline of

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/ \& /g'  -e 's/$/\\\\/' -e '1i\\\\begin{tabular}{*{20}{l}}' -e '$a\\\\end{tabular}' d.txt
```

Produces

```
\begin{tabular}{*{20}{l}}
x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x & x & x\\
x & x\\
x & x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x\\
x & x & x & x & x\\
\end{tabular}
```

Which you could either do before running latex or (using --shell-escape) on the fly during the latex run.

Comment: I should have given more background - the table are coordinates that I intend to draw various rectangles with in TikZ.  So actually I don't want to produce a table in LaTeX.

Comment: @M.P. well same applies actually, whatever syntax would be convenient to read from tikz you could generate instead of the tabular, just by tweaking the sed.